# Get value between from to dataset columns ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, sqlreportingservice

I have a data set like that:

Data Set Contents

```
From  To Comment 
----+---+-------- 
0    50   Bad 

50   70   Good 

70   100  Excellent
```

If I have a value of 75, I need to get Excellent by searching the Dataset.
I know about the lookup function but it is not what I want. How can I do that? 
The values should be in percentage.

> Note : the value (75) is Average of a column (Calculated)  it
>   calculate student grade from max and student mark Version SQL Server
>   2016
>
> Note 2 : the dataset is from database not static values

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only ever have a fixed number of 'grades' then this will work. However, I would strongly recommend doing this type of work on the server where possible.

Here we go...

I created two datasets
**dsGradeRange** with the following sql to recreate your example (more or less)

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (low int, high int, comment varchar(20))

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(0,49,'Bad'),
(50,69,'Good'),
(70,100, 'Excellent')

SELECT * FROM @t
```

**dsRandomNumbers** This just creates 30 random numbers between 0 and 100

```
SELECT * 
    FROM (SELECT top 30 ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 100) as myNumber FROM sys.objects) x
    ORDER BY myNumber
```

I added a table to the report to show the grades (just for reference).

I then added a table to show the `dsRandomNumbers`

Finally I set the expression of the 2nd column to the following expression.

```
=SWITCH
    (
        Fields!myNumber.Value < LOOKUP("Bad", Fields!comment.Value, Fields!high.Value, "dsGradeRange"), "Bad",
        Fields!myNumber.Value < LOOKUP("Good", Fields!comment.Value, Fields!high.Value, "dsGradeRange"), "Good",
        True, "Excellent"
    )
```

This gives the following results

[image]

As you can see we only need to compare to the high value of each case, the first match will return the correct comment.

Comment: thank you for answer  your answer assume i know the value of the Comment Field second i have to put the "dsGradeRange " on the report to compare am i Correct because you never reference the "dsGradeRange " in the formula ??

Comment: You don't need the grade table on the report. That was just so you could see the dataset. DsGradeRange is referenced in the lookup part switch statement.

Comment: Lookup("Bad"    the values can change in db i can't put it static values

Comment: Fields!comment.Value  it is not in report datasource it is separate dataset

Comment: =SWITCH
    (
        Fields!k1Value.Value < LOOKUP("Bad", (Fields!Comment.Value, "DS"), (Fields!ThTo.Value, "DS"), "DS"), "Bad",
        Fields!k1Value.Value < LOOKUP("Good",(Fields!Comment.Value, "DS"), (Fields!ThTo.Value, "DS"), "DS"), "Good",
        True, "Excellent"
    )  i replaced Field!Comment with dataset field it give error

Comment: the comment was from the dataset example you posted. You need to edit your question and show sample data from all your datasets as I don;t understand what the problem is.

Comment: the dataset sample is correct but since it is coming from database i cant use a static value "Bad" some one can change it to "Weak" i need of the value between From - to i print the corresponding label

Comment: This is why I suggested a calculated field, which serves the same purpose as @Alans first Sql statement, which is using the From and To values. I am confused now

Comment: Confused?? it is simple i have a lookup table "DegreeNames" has range of degrees From to and a text ie from 0 to 49 Fail from 50 to 75 Pass etc i need to print student certificate take student degree then get the text based on his result from the lookup  i don't think it is confusing the only thing that it is database table so any value can change from or to or the text so i don't want to put static text or numbers in the report formula

Comment: You could just build a flat list of values/grades rather than the ranged dataset then just do a simple lookup. This might be easier than doing it all in the dataset query. So your list would be (assuming percentages) 100 values each with the correct comment, then in SSRS a simple lookup to get the value by looking up the score.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your dataset and add a calculated field. Go to **Field Properties > Fields > Add** and add the following expression, which descripes your scenario:

```
=IIF(Fields!Number.Value < 50, "Bad", "Good")
```

Comment: the values of the dataset is from database i need to get the field comment if the value is between from - to

Comment: Ah ok, then load your field in the Dataset and reference it with `Fields!Comment.Value` in the filter for example

Comment: the value from and to is also from database so i can't filter <50 and i want between

Comment: Do you mean a filter like that `=Fields!From.Value > 50 And Fields!To.Value < 70`. This will filter all values with `Good`.

Comment: i mean =Fields!From.Value > dataset.From  And Fields!To.Value < dataset.to